# Download XML file instead of having browser open. MVC

Tags: xml, model-view-controller

I have a report that makes an XML file.  When it runs it automatically opens the xml file in the browser instead of downloading an xml file onto the computer.
How do I change this in my controller?

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Report(reportViewMode model)
{
    var yearSetupId = _db.GetYearSetup(model.YearSetupId).YearSetupId;
    var result = _db.GetUnpaidBalanceReportRows(yearSetupId);

    return new XmlResult(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about a web application returning some XML to the browser and that you wish to open up the download dialog of your browser instead of displaying the content, you should set an appropriate `Content-Type` of the response. `application/xml` might be a good choice in this case.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this whole thing.  Could you provide a generic example?

Comment: Not without knowing the package of `XmlResult` or `ActionResult`.